# Sinatra: concerning filters, halt and body on 404 error

Tags: json, http, sinatra

I'm using Sinatra to develop this JSON API. The way I designed it, the error messages are also delivered in JSON in a specific format. The only difference is that they response will have a 4xx status code instead of a 2xx or 3xx. Now, the problems I encountered:

- I defined a general filter where I set the response content type. Like this:

  ```
  before { content_type :json }
  ```

  problem is, everytime I call halt, this setting is not taken into account. I have to set it myself on the halt call in a very ugly, more verbose and error-prone way:

  ```
  halt [404, {"Content-Type" => "application/json;charset=utf-8"}]
  ```

  is there another way to do this?
- The problem that phases me the most is: when I halt with code 404 after I catch the 404 error (see below), JSON content type and json body, strangely, I don't get any body, neither browser nor curl gets it. How come?

  ```
  error 404 do
    halt [404...{"bang" => "bong"....}]
  end
  ```

UPDATE

Concerning the last issue, here is what it happens using curl and triggering a call which will fall in the 404 error block:

```
curl http://faulty_url

# curl log:
curl: (52) Empty reply from server

# sinatra log:
!! Unexpected error while processing request: Content-Length header was 221, but should be 227
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2013 11:28:47] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 221 0.0664
```

maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand exactly what's the output, but if you are looking to override 404 you will have to do something like below instead of `error 404 do`

```
not_found do
    # Set content
    {"bang" => "bong"}
end
```

Comment: it is a good input, but it didn't solve the problem. don't forget, i'm halting again with code 404 on this block and a json body, i'm not simply returning the body.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Sinatra were you using? Looking at the recent change logs for Sinatra I see two entries in the 1.4.x releases that seem like they could be relevant:

- Status, headers and body will be set correctly in an after filter when using halt in a before filter or route. (Konstantin Haase)
- Setting status code to 404 in error handler no longer triggers not_found handler. (Konstantin Haase)

Comment: the question is not whether they are correctly handled. They are. They just removed the response options I might have set before. Like the content type I set on a before filter. As soon as I halt, it's gone.